# Php making array of pictures with parameters from folder/picture name

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, url, path

So I'm trying to do an import of shop's products. In the database I have all the product info I need (ID, name). The tricky part - pictures.

There's a product picture folder, which has a structure like this:

```
Manufacturer folder -> .jpg's named "XXX - name_name_name" where XXX - product ID.
```

For example - `"C:/pictures/nike/100 - shoes1.jpg"`

There are about 20 manufacturers (folders), about 8K products total.

If I specify a path to the picture folder, how could I get data like "manufacturer name(folder name), product id (cut out from full name), picture url" for each picture that I could use to compare with the database entries and set the correct picture for the product? Is it even worth making such array with php?

Example product database entry:

---

ID    Name

100    Nike_shoes1

---

What I get from select query (only ID usable, product name in DB and on the picture may differ)

```
array(25) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["category"]=>
    string(10) "6"
    ["ID"]=>
    string(20) "1659"
    ["name"]=>
    string(70) "Relyx U100 TR 56839 (3M) - nebetiekiama"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "286.69"
    ["qnt"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["COL 6"]=>
    string(4) "vnt"
    ["pvm"]=>
    string(5) "21.00"
    ["COL 8"]=>
    string(9) "20140 "
  }
```

so the result should be something like: 
(pictures array)

```
["pictureUrl"]=>
    string(10) "C:/pictures/nike/100 - Nike_shoes1.jpg"
["manufacturer"]=>
    string(10) "nike"
["id"]=>
    string(10) "100"
```

and then I could compare it to what I have, like

```
foreach ($pictures as $key => $picture){
    if($product['id'] == $picture['id']) {
        $product['picture'] = $picture['pictureUrl'];
        $product['manufacturer'] = $picture['manufacturer'];
    } 
}
```

Let me know if the question is appropriate, or if I should add anything.

Comment: Do you store the full url in the db or just the image file name as you mentioned? I mean how do you associate the image with it's dir to be displays at the end? In other words, how do you get the final URL for the image?

Comment: Is the images name standardized with the structure you mentined?

Comment: There are no associations, that's the problem. In the database I have only products with their IDs, no manufacturers no pictures nothing. And on the other side I have a folder with pictures whose names start with product ID and then name, and they are in a folder that's named after manufacturer. I need to retrieve something like "nike,100,C:/pictures/nike/100 - Nike_shoes1.jpg"
And no, the name of picture after "ID - " and DB can be different.

Comment: wait, how are you running your local server? xampp? you cannot access the C root directly like that. The images dir must be placed inside your php project folder.

Comment: I can place them anywhere, just posted as an example.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? May I ask why you want it to be in that format?

Comment: Basically it just has to be an array with those 3 variables, I posted an edit with what I would use to compare it, should clear it up

Comment: To ease it up for you, may I know how you retrieve the data from the database? I mean what is the output array after you operate the SELECT statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Place the pictures folder in your php dir, assuming you have a project named `products` in your www, or home, or htdocs. i.g  C:/xampp/htdocs/products/images
2. From what I see, you have all the info in the image name (I hope the images names are standardized the way you mentioned)
3. Let's start operation:

Fetch images names from db:

**pseudo code**

```
$images_list = $images->getAllAssoc("id","image_name");

//prints: 
array(
[100]=>"Nike_shoes1"
[200]=>"Nike_shoes2"
[300]=>"Nike_shoes3"
)

//Now let's loop and generate the output
$image_base_url="pictures";//can change 
foreach ($images_list as $image_id => $image_name)
{
    $image_parts= explode("_", $image_name); // [0]=Nike, [1]=shoes1

    $img_arr["manufacturer"] = $image_parts[0];
    $img_arr["id"] = $image_id;
    $img_arr["pictureUrl"] = "{$image_base_url}/{$img_arr["manufacturer"]}/{$image_id} - {$image_name}";///pictures/nike/100 - Nike_shoes1.jpg

//compose in the final result array
$producs_images[] =$img_arr;

}
```

UPDATE:

Based on your comments I At least this is how I would do it if I were you. 
I will create a new table (or add a new column/field in the db) and call it 'manufacturer'. So by knowing the manufacturer of your product, you can easily locate the image.

My approach will be to create a new field in the products table and call it 'manufacturer ' and then go your picture directory and loop through all folders to 1-capture the manufacturer name. 2-get all the ids of products in it. I assume the products are the folders names under the manif folder. And then update the manufacturer column in your db. 
Be careful that the full url I used to access my local pic file in my windows machine. You need to edit to suites yours whether in localhost or later on a production server.

**My structure is as the following:**

[image]

Example code:

```
$main_dir = "\SERVER\htdocs\phpProject1\pictures";
$dir_list = new ParentIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($main_dir));
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_list, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
// Optionally, limit the depth of recursion with $it->setMaxDepth($number)
$it = iterator_to_array($it, true);
$c = 1;
foreach ($it as $dir) {
    echo $dir;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    $chunks = explode("\\", $dir);

    $arr["manif"] = $chunks[5];
    if ($c !== 1) {
        $arr["prodcut_id"] = $chunks[6];
        $p_arr[] = $arr;
    }
    $c++;
}
print_r($p_arr);
```

**Output:**

```
\SERVER\htdocs\phpProject1\pictures\nike
\SERVER\htdocs\phpProject1\pictures\nike\100
\SERVER\htdocs\phpProject1\pictures\nike\200
\SERVER\htdocs\phpProject1\pictures\nike\300
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mani] => nike
            [prodcut_id] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mani] => nike
            [prodcut_id] => 200
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mani] => nike
            [prodcut_id] => 300
        )

)
Done.
```

Now you have the product id with it's manufacturer together collected from the picture folder, what you need to do is to update the manufacturer column you added to the db based on the product id.

Comment: I'm not sure if I explained it right, but I don't think the product names in the DB exactly match the picture names, so we could only use the ID, that both the product in the DB and the picture in the beinning of its name have. The 'nike' part (manufacturer) should be taken from the FOLDER name, not all products have manufacturer in their names.

Comment: I've edited in an example result from my select query (shows 1 out of 8000 products, can't use the names on there though)

Comment: this seems quite bigger than anticipated. Just to confirm my understanding, you mean there's no way to link between the image record in db and it's manufacturer except for it's ID which is located in the picture folder. e.g if you have picture id 75, then it will be in pictures/nike/75?

Comment: There is no image record in the db. There are product records with ID. And there are manufacturer-name folders with pictures inside of them that have names of following format: "productID - name". So basically I need to generate an array of pictures from those folders, that would have full picture path, manufacturer name (folder name) and product id (taken from the picture name). Yup, it's complicated as hell

Comment: yup yup, so linking between the product id in db and the image in pictures folder. pictures/nike/100. I had a similar issue a few years back. What I can think of now is to write a patch code to fix this issue permanently. For short, if you know the manufacturer of a certain product located in db I think that will help you locate the image directly right?

Comment: I don't know the manufacturer in the products table, that's the thing. I have to get it from the folder name in which there's a picture with same ID as the product :D

Comment: I've updated the answer. Hope that gives some pointers on how to tackle the issue.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to do everything! However I just noticed, you thought that the '100' is a new folder, while in reality it's part of the picture name (like in the example I gave "100 - shoes1.jpg"

Comment: Hey, just saw your comment. In case you haven't figured it out yet, what you could do is use *explode* function, it's your help in this case. To chunk out the part of the name that you could use as the image ID. For example use **explode** and pass "-" as the first parameter to break the name from that and get array with two indexes, the first one will be your image id (remember to strip out the space)